# Join multiple tables Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Laravel version 4.2**

I am trying to Join multiple tables and get results

I have now 2 tables

1- projects_info (id - pro_title - pro_address ...)

2- projects_images (id - image - image_id)

I need to grape the related images from the 'projects_images' where image_id = projects_info id

here what I try

here is my Route

```
//Projects Route
Route::get('our-projects', 'projectController@currentProjects');
Route::get('project/{id}', 'projectController@viewProject');

//Projects details
//Route::get('project/{id}/about-project', 'projectController@viewProject');
Route::get('project/{id}/about-project', array('as' => 'about-project', 'uses' => 'projectController@viewProject'));
Route::get('project/{id}/project-images', array('as' => 'project-images', 'uses' => 'projectController@viewProjectImages'));
```

Projects Model

```
    class Projects extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
    {

        use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

        protected $table = 'project_info_arabic';

        public function projectImages()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('ProjectsImages', 'image_id');
        }

    }
```

ProjectsImages Model

```
    class ProjectsImages extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
    {
        use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

        protected $table = 'projects_images';

        public function project()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('Projects', 'id');
        }
    }
```

and this is my ProjectController

```
public function currentProjects()
    {
        $pro = Projects::all();
        return View::make('projects.currentProjects', ['pro' => $pro]);
    }

    public function viewProject($id)
    {
        $vp = Projects::find($id);
        return View::make('projects.viewProject', ['viewPro' => $vp]);
    }

    public function viewProjectImages($id)
    {
        $vpi = ProjectsImages::with('project')->get();
        //$vpi = DB::table('projects_images')->select('id', 'image', 'image_id')->get();
        return View::make('projects.projectDetails.projectImages', ['viewProImg' => $vpi]);
    }
```

and here is how I am trying to include each page in my projectsDetails VIEW

```
<div class="mCustomScrollbar">
                                @if(Request::path()=="project/$viewPro->id/about-project")
                                    @include('projects.projectDetails.aboutProject')
                                @elseif(Request::path()=="project/$viewPro->id")
                                    @include('projects.projectDetails.aboutProject')
                                @elseif(Request::path()=="project/$viewPro->id/project-images")
                                    @include('projects.projectDetails.projectImages')
                                @endif
                            </div>
```

and last the projectImages VIEW

```
<ul>
            @foreach($viewProImg as $vpi)
                <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    {{ HTML::image("images/projects/$vpi->image", '', array('class'=>'img-responsive')) }}
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
```

**My Problem**

1- what I got here is all the images in the table it should be only the images related to this project

any help here please

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel version  4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the project **has many** images

```
public function projectImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProjectsImage');
}
```

.. and the image **belongs to** a project

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
}
```

You should always refer to the model. If you are referring to a model then you should have in mind that its good practice to name the models in singular form, as in Project and ProjectImage. In Laravel, they expect you to have name the tables name in plural and the model name in singular. So if you haven't explicit set the table name, it will look for the model name plus a s (ProjectS).

Then, you can call the projectImages -function from a Project object. So in the view it will look something like this

```
@foreach($project->projectImages()->get() as $image)
    // Do what you want with each project images
@endforeach
```

Comment: I did what you just said but come back with error `Undefined variable: project (View: C:\wamp\www\elarabiaLaravel\app\views\projects\projectDetails\projectImages.blade.php) ` what `$project` should be here in the `View`

Comment: It depends on which function being called on the controller but for the viewProject -function you pass the variable as "viewPro" so replace $project with $viewPro in your blade-file